# Hadoop error -"connection refused"?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, connection, hdfs

I got the following error in Hadoop cluster . I ran a job ,and it was long and couldn't finish .
Then whenever I try to access Hdfs ,I get:

"Call From li417-43.members.linode.com/174.79.191.40 to li417-43.members.linode.com:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused"

Any way to solve this!

Thanks

Comment: Your namenode went down. run jps and check if name node is up or not? Check for logs why it went down andy exception error etc?

Comment: I can't run jps command: "command not found"!

Comment: set JAVA_HOME and then try JPS..

Comment: I got this after runing jps:"30037 Jps"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:  no java processes are running and thus neither the NameNode nor JobTracker are running.  The particular error 8020 refers to the NameNode: HDFS is not up.

Depending on the version of Hadoop you may be able to do

```
start-dfs.sh
start-mapred.sh
```

OR

```
start-all.sh
```

After that you will need to examine the HDFS logs to see what are the issues. You may also post log entries here for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks javadba.Indeed namenode was off ,I turned it on. the log file is under var/log/hadoop-hdfs..it's a huge file!

Comment: Anything else you need to know or is this an answer you can accept?

Comment: That's fine -I think the problem was with heap and disk space. How I can set this for Hadoop? . Thank you